# Sending CMD command prompts using Subprocess (Python)

Tags: python, cmd, automation, subprocess, virtualenv

This is a beginner level question for anyone pro in `subprocess`.

In Windows, is it possible for me to send the following CMD commands using `subprocess`such  that they are ***executed one after another in a single shell***:

1. cd C:\Users\User\myvirtualenvs\project1
2. Scripts\activate.bat
3. Hello.py

Effectively, I am trying to load  the Virtualenv without having to manually myself touch CMD prompt.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think (but I’m no `cmd` expert) that you separate the commands with `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

Just like mentioned in the Comment with `&&`:

```
from subprocess import call

call(r'cd C:\ && echo 123 && dir', shell=True)
```

Please notice the `shell=True` argument.

Edit due to comment:

`Shell=True` is an security issue, if you're passing raw input values to the call. See this example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

```
from subprocess import call
filename = input("What file would you like to display?\n")
>>> What file would you like to display?
>>> non_existent; rm -rf / #
call("cat " + filename, shell=True) # Uh-oh. This will end badly...
```

In initially thought you want to make a small script for personal purposes. If you want to give this code away, think about packaging your code via distutils or setuptools.

Comment: "cd C:\\" <- double backslashes! Or use raw strings.

Comment: Thank you. I am planning to give this program to other users eventually and hence I would like to ask if its possible to do it without "shell=True" as I heard that it has some security issues.

Comment: Just as a side note, in the meanwhile, I did manage to do the above thingies using AutoIT :D, but yes if I can have a clean python way to do it, it would be preferrable :)

Comment: As long as you completely control the input string, it is "safe" to use `shell=True`. One way or another you are forced to open a subshell, in order to run your commands in sequence and have them remember the settings from `activate.bat`. And, as soon as you have opened a subshell, shell commands can be run from within it. Also, if you are afraid of malicious usage, it is equally dangerous to just allow the user access to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: As a sidenote, why are you not just making a very simple `.bat` file instead, doing what you want? What is the benefit of using a Python `subprocess`?